# Basic linux regex

Tags: regex, linux

I'm learning about Linux command line and have come across a regular expression that has me stumped.

Can someone run through this and explain what its doing please. I know this first part as read will use REPLY as a variable if none is supplied.

```
read -p "Enter a single item > "

# is input a valid filename?
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[-[:alnum:]\._]+$ ]]; then 
        echo "'$REPLY' is a valid file name."
```

Like why is [- in there? Is it checking to see if the start of $REPLY is a dash? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression is:

```
^         -- Start of the string
[         -- Character class start
-         -- A literal dash
[:alnum:] -- POSIX-style alphanumeric (a-z, 0-9)
.         -- A literal period
_         -- A literal underscore
]         -- End character class
+         -- One or more of anything in the character class
$         -- End of the string
```

The `-` is a literal dash.  It is at the start of the character class so that it is not interpreted as a class range.  For example, `[a-c]` is `a, b, c`, but `[-ac]` is `-, a, c`

---

As an aside, this is an incomplete check for a filename.  As far as I know, filenames can contain any character except directory separators (e.g. `/`) -- even spaces and newlines in any amount.